# NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?'

Tags: ruby, upload, task, capistrano, webdeploy

Today (I don't know why!!!!) I cannot deploy my project with capistrano.

When I launch this task

```
namespace :deploy do

  # Theme path
  set :theme_path, Pathname.new('web/app/themes').join(fetch(:theme_name))

  # Local Paths
  set :local_theme_path, Pathname.new(File.dirname(__FILE__)).join('../').join(fetch(:theme_path))
  set :local_dist_path, fetch(:local_theme_path).join('dist')

  task :compile do
    run_locally do
      within fetch(:local_theme_path) do
        execute "git checkout #{fetch(:branch)}"
        execute :gulp, '--production'
      end
    end
  end

  task :copy do
    on roles(:web) do

      # Remote Paths (Lazy-load until actual deploy)
      set :remote_dist_path, -> { release_path.join(fetch(:theme_path)).join('dist') }

      info " Your local distribution path: #{fetch(:local_dist_path)} "
      info " Boom!!! Your remote distribution path: #{fetch(:remote_dist_path)} "
      info " Uploading files to remote "
      upload! fetch(:local_dist_path).to_s, fetch(:remote_dist_path), recursive: true
    end
  end

  task assets: %w(compile copy)
end
```

Capistrano print this error

> (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
>
> cap aborted!
>
> SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ec2->user@*********: undefined method `start_with?' for #Pathname:0x0000*fc***a****
>
> Caused by:
>
> NoMethodError: undefined method `start_with?' for #Pathname:0x0000*fc***a****

I try all: uninstall node, ruby, etc... ma nothing change.
Someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: What did you change recently? Something related to paths, I'm sure.

Comment: On my server ruby -v = ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: I do only some "gem updates"...

Comment: Did you update the capistrano itself? Guess it doesn't stringifies its pathnames anymore. Try adding `.to_s` on the pathnames.

Comment: Yep!!! It works! But until yesterday everything worked without it!

Comment: Until yesterday you used other gems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
upload! fetch(:local_dist_path).to_s, fetch(:remote_dist_path), recursive: true
```

should be

```
upload! fetch(:local_dist_path).to_s, fetch(:remote_dist_path).to_s, recursive: true
```

(call `to_s` on both `Pathname`s.)

Comment: Some erroneous code was working because of the bug/issue in one of gems you were using was not of the recent version. So what? It expects a string, not a pathname. Period.

Comment: The error is due to a bug introduced in sshkit 1.15.0 (a gem used by Capistrano). It will be fixed in a forthcoming release. In the meantime the `to_s` workaround is perfectly valid. https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/issues/409